# Gamma Family Density Function of Y

Tags: exponential-function, gamma-function, gamma-distribution

[image]

I have tried to think of how to prove this but at a loss.  I keep getting it squared so not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would just use the following formula for a one-to-one transformation of a random variable:  if $Y = g(X)$ where $g$ is invertible, then $$f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \left| \frac{dg^{-1}}{dy} \right|.$$  So with $Y = g(X) = X^{1/\gamma}$, we have $X = g^{-1}(Y) = Y^\gamma$, and the rest is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(Y \le y)
&= \mathbb{P}(X^{1/\gamma} \le y)\\
&= \mathbb{P}(X \le y^\gamma)\\
&= 1-e^{- y^{\gamma}/\beta}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
f_Y(y)
&= \frac{d}{dy} \mathbb{P}(Y \le y)\\
&= \frac{\gamma}{\beta} y^{\gamma-1} e^{-y^\gamma/\beta}
\end{align*}